# What's wrong with this sentence, and how to write it properly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, conjunctions

> However repeated assurances that the product is safe, many people stopped buying it.

There is an error in this sentence, but I couldn't correct it.

I thought first about changing, However to Despite, but I couldn't identify what's wrong with the sentence.

Comment: The use of **despite** would do the trick. Otherwise, the sentence has to be rewritten: *However (in spite of receiving) repeated assurances that the product is safe, many people stopped buying it.*

Comment: An alternative to **despite** would be ***However many** assurances they were given that the product was safe, people stopped buying it.* Here's an example of that usage: https://books.google.com/books?id=NFAbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT7999&dq=%22however+many%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja7K6NpJnaAhVCU98KHf6TC94Q6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22however%20many%22&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Macmillian Dictionary:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/however)
**However** can used as an adverb (before an adjective or adverb):

> However hard he tried, he could not control his feelings.
>
> However much they earn, they will never be satisfied.

Applying this to your sentence could give you something like

> However often they repeated assurances that the product is safe, many people
>   stopped buying it.

Or, like Tᴚoɯɐuo suggested,

> However many assurances they were given that the product was safe,
>   people stopped buying it.

Answer (score 0):

"Despite having repeated assurance that the product is safe, many people stopped buying it"
You have to use Despite to show contrast. Despite is always followed by -ing form.
It's better to sat assurance (without s)
I used "Having repeated" to show that the second clause occurs after the first one is completed.

Comment: Despite can be followed by a noun.